# Magento 1.5.1 - How can I add the customer's billing email address to success.phtml

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I've added the following code to the Magento 1.5.1 order confirmation page (success.phtml):

```
<?php
    $_order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); // here I get the Oreder ID
    $_order->load($_order_id);
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $email = $customer->getEmail();  // To get Email Address of a customer.
?>

An email confirmation was sent to: <?php echo $email ?>
```

Unfortunately the email variable is empty/null.

Does anyone know how to efficiently get this data? Obtaining First and Last name would be a bonus.

Keep in mind that guest checkout is allowed, so we may not have a customer record in all cases. In any case, I need the billing email address assosicated with the order (guest checkout or not.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got the Order object maybe you can use:

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
```

I think that this method it better because you can use it for Guest Customers too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is correct and is exactly what I ended up doing. I returned to answer the question myself and found that you already posted it. Thank you...I was beginning to lose a little faith in the Magento community as I thought this would have been the second (of 2) Magento-related questions I was going to have to answer...and I'm not a Magento developer.

Answer (score 0):

You have the order increment number ther so load the order and get the variable from order object

Comment: Hello Anton, I do also have $_order->load($_order_id); in the code, but I tried loading the email from there and it didn't work out for me. If you could post sample code, I could try it.

Comment: You dont have the entity id but increment id so you should load  by increment id